# normal translation for "to need to do something"

Tags: translation, modal-verb

I've read in several places that it's ok to use *brauchen* when you want to say it isn't necessary to do something, e.g.

> Er braucht nicht die Bücher zu lesen.

But I'm struggling to find a reference anywhere to using it in this quasi-modal manner for something that it is necessary to do, e.g.

> I need to buy a new car.

Should we just use *müssen* or *es ist mir nötig*?

Comment: Since no answer addresses this: *es ist mir nötig* is not idiomatic. One could use *Es ist nötig, dass ich ...* instead.

Answer (score 3):

> I need to buy a new car.

translates either to

> Ich **muss** ein neues Auto kaufen.

or

> Ich brauche ein neues Auto. *(note the ommitted **kaufen**)*

That is because the simple *brauchen* cannot be combined with another verb, in contrary to *müssen*, *sollen*, *können*. However, with *nicht brauchen* another verb is perfectly okay.

> Ich brauche kein neues Auto **zu** kaufen.
>
> Ich brauche kein neues Auto.

are both correct. That's similar to English *must*, which has a different meaning when used negatively. (Note that **zu** is required by the rulebook, though many many many German speakers will leave it out. There's even a mnemonic for that: *Wer brauchen ohne zu gebraucht, braucht brauchen gar nicht zu gebrauchen.*)

Comment: Yes, as I had wrote it.

Comment: Although *Ich brauche ein neues Auto* closer translates to *I **need** a new car* (note the omitted *to buy).*

Answer (score 1):

Option 1: You can use *'müssen'* (natural language usage)

> I need to buy a new car.
>
> *Ich muss ein neues Auto kaufen.*
>
> It is necessary that you wash your car.
>
> *Du musst dein Auto waschen.*

Option 2: You can use *'es ist notwendig, dass ...'* (formal)
Normally not used in daily language.

> It is necessary to improve the operating result by 10% next year.
>
> *Es ist notwendig das Betriebsergebnis zum nächsten Jahr um 10% zu verbessern.*
>
> It is necessary that you wash your car.
>
> *Es ist notwendig, dass du dein Auto wäschst.*

Comment: Die Sätze mit "notwendig" klingen für mich ziemlich gekünstelt. Ist das regional?

Comment: Nein, "notwendig" wird eher im formalen Kontext benutzt. So zum Beispiel in Unternehmen während eines Meetings: "Es ist notwendig das Betriebsergebnis zum nächsten Jahr um 10% zu verbessern."

Comment: Könntest Du das in Deiner Antwort klarer machen, vielleicht mit einem anderen Beispiel anstelle des "Auto kaufen"? Dann könnne wir diese Kommentare löschen und alles ist direkt in der Antwort.